# python3 regex returns empty tuple

Tags: python, regex, python-3.4

I'm trying to apply regex to gather data from a file, and I only get empty results. For example, this little test (`python3.4.3`)

```
import re

a = 'abcde'
r = re.search('a',a)
print(r.groups())
exit()
```

Results with empty tuple (`()`). Clearly, I'm doing something wrong here, but what?

*Comment:*
What I'm actually trying to do is to interpret expressions such as `0.7*sqrt(2)`, by finding the value inside the parenthesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because there are no groups in your regex. If you replace it with:

```
>>> r = re.search('(a)',a)
```

you'll get the groups:

```
>>> print(r.groups())
('a',)
```

Using `group` should work with the first option:

```
>>> print(re.search('a',a).group())
a
```

Answer (score 2):

`r.groups()` returns an empty tuple, because your regular expression did not contain any group.

```
>>> import re
>>> a = 'abcde'
>>> re.search('a', a)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='a'>
>>> re.search('a', a).groups()
()
>>> re.search('(a)', a).groups()
('a',)
```

Have a look at the `re` module [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

> (...)
>       Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, and indicates the start and end of a group;

Edit: If you want to catch the bit between the brackets in the expression `O.7*sqrt(2)`, you could use the following pattern:

```
>>> re.search('[\d\.]+\*sqrt\((\d)\)', '0.7*sqrt(2)').group(1)
'2'
```